# logging sqlite access in Coredata

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I´m using CoreData with a sqlite store.
Is it possible to log the sqlite queries CoreData sends to the DB-layer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the following as an argument to the application to log to stderr the actual SQL sent to SQLite:

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002320-SW1